# Spring Security Authorize Tag - HTTP Status 500

Tags: spring, jsp, security

I'm trying to hide or show some parts of the .jsp page using the authorize tag.
I have tried the bellow code, hasRole, isAuthenticated() or anything else gives error:

> HTTP Status 500 - org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception
>   occurred processing JSP page

```
<sec:authorize access="hasRole('USER')">
    show something
</sec:authorize>
```

Spring Security configs:

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd">
    <http auto-config="true" >
        <intercept-url pattern="/" access="permitAll" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/home/**" access="hasRole('USER')" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/user/profile/**" access="hasRole('USER')" />
        <form-login  login-page="/login" username-parameter="ssoId" password-parameter="password" authentication-failure-url="/Access_Denied" />
        <csrf/>
    </http>
    <authentication-manager >
        <authentication-provider>
        <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"
          users-by-username-query=
            "select USER_NAME, USER_PASS, USER_ENABLED from USERS where USER_NAME=?"
          authorities-by-username-query=
            "select USER_NAME, USER_ROLE from USER_ROLES where USER_NAME=?" />
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>
</beans:beans>
```

> HTTP Status 500 - javax.servlet.ServletException:
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   org.springframework.security.web.context.support.SecurityWebApplicationContextUtils.findWebApplicationContext(Ljavax/servlet/ServletContext;)Lorg/springframework/web/context/WebApplicationContext;
>
> type Exception report
>
> message javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   org.springframework.security.web.context.support.SecurityWebApplicationContextUtils.findWebApplicationContext(Ljavax/servlet/ServletContext;)Lorg/springframework/web/context/WebApplicationContext;
>
> description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it
>   from fulfilling this request.
>
> exception
>
> org.apache.jasper.JasperException: javax.servlet.ServletException:
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   org.springframework.security.web.context.support.SecurityWebApplicationContextUtils.findWebApplicationContext(Ljavax/servlet/ServletContext;)Lorg/springframework/web/context/WebApplicationContext;
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:555)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:461)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
>     org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:168)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:303)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1244)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1027)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:971)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:857)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
>     org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:316)
>     org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:126)
>     org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
>     org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
>     org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:122)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
>     org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
>     org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:169)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
>     org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:48)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
>     org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:158)
>     org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
>     org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:205)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
>     org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:120)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
>     org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:96)
>     org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
>     org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64)
>     org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
>     org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:53)
>     org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
>     org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:91)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:213)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:176)
>     org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
>     org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
>
> root cause
>
> javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   org.springframework.security.web.context.support.SecurityWebApplicationContextUtils.findWebApplicationContext(Ljavax/servlet/ServletContext;)Lorg/springframework/web/context/WebApplicationContext;
>     org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doHandlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:909)
>     org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.handlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:838)
>     org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.home_jsp._jspService(home_jsp.java:221)
>     org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:438)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
>     org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:168)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:303)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1244)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1027)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:971)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:857)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
>     org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:316)
>     org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:126)
>     org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
>     org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
>     org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:122)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
>     org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
>     org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:169)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
>     org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:48)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
>     org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:158)
>     org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
>     org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:205)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
>     org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:120)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
>     org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:96)
>     org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
>     org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64)
>     org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
>     org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:53)
>     org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
>     org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:91)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:213)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:176)
>     org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
>     org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
>
> root cause
>
> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   org.springframework.security.web.context.support.SecurityWebApplicationContextUtils.findWebApplicationContext(Ljavax/servlet/ServletContext;)Lorg/springframework/web/context/WebApplicationContext;
>     org.springframework.security.web.context.support.SecurityWebApplicationContextUtils.findRequiredWebApplicationContext(SecurityWebApplicationContextUtils.java:46)
>     org.springframework.security.taglibs.authz.AbstractAuthorizeTag.getExpressionHandler(AbstractAuthorizeTag.java:205)
>     org.springframework.security.taglibs.authz.AbstractAuthorizeTag.authorizeUsingAccessExpression(AbstractAuthorizeTag.java:127)
>     org.springframework.security.taglibs.authz.AbstractAuthorizeTag.authorize(AbstractAuthorizeTag.java:99)
>     org.springframework.security.taglibs.authz.JspAuthorizeTag.doStartTag(JspAuthorizeTag.java:54)
>     org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.home_jsp._jspx_meth_sec_005fauthorize_005f0(home_jsp.java:315)
>     org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.home_jsp._jspService(home_jsp.java:162)
>     org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:438)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
>     org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:168)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:303)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1244)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1027)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:971)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:857)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
>     org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:316)
>     org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:126)
>     org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
>     org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
>     org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:122)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
>     org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
>     org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:169)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
>     org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:48)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
>     org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:158)
>     org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
>     org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:205)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
>     org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:120)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
>     org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:96)
>     org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
>     org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64)
>     org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
>     org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:53)
>     org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
>     org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:91)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:213)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:176)
>     org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
>     org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)

Comment: Have you included Spring Security taglib declaration in your JSP? Also please post the whole whole stack trace from server logs.

Comment: Yes i always include taglibs. I'm now getting a new error which im posting now.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found where the problem was, i was using a bit lower version of spring framework.

Comment: spring-security 4.0.3 depends on spring 4.2.x, it seems. In contrast, spring-security 4.0.2 works with spring 4.1.x, at least in my project.

Comment: so nice that you have figured that out you have solved my problem too but  where to know what spring security ver to use with spring ver other than the migration guide ?

Comment: @Dunken I often had the same problem - I highly recommend to use Spring IO platform (platform.spring.io). You can either use it directly in your pom.xml or at least check what are the recommended mix of libraries you should use together (especially when using Spring MVC and Security). 

You see all the versions here for the latest mix ("Brussels"):
https://docs.spring.io/platform/docs/Brussels-SR5/reference/htmlsingle/#appendix-dependency-versions

Or to see an older version
https://docs.spring.io/platform/docs/1.1.5.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#appendix-dependency-versions

Answer (score 0):

it is not just related to version of spring but also take care of versions compatibility , same issue happened with me on spring 4.1.6 and spring security 4.0.3 but solved when upgrade spring to version 4.2.2.
here is useful link for compatible versions.
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-taglibs