# Spring Security sec:authorize throw exception

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc, spring-security, jsp-tags

I want to add a field to my jsp which will be shown only to admin. For this purpose I use tag sec:authorize access="hasRole('Admin')". But when I add it, application throws exception: http://pastebin.com/TcN0k0K0 
I use spring 4.1.7.RELEASE, spring-security version 4.0.3.RELEASE. In pom.xml I've added spring-security-taglibs v.4.0.3
here is my jsp code:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="sec" uri="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags" %>
<html>
<body>    
<sec:authorize access="hasRole('Admin')">
    <p>Must have ROLE_Admin to see this</p>
</sec:authorize>    
<form name='registerForm' method='POST' action="/admin/createuser">
        ...
```

in database role stored as ROLE_Admin, ROLE_User

spring-security.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
             xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security

     http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.0.xsd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd">

<http use-expressions="true" >
    <csrf disabled="true"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/admin" access="hasAnyRole('Admin', 'User')" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/login" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/logout" access="permitAll" />

    <access-denied-handler error-page="/403" />

    <form-login login-page='/login' login-processing-url="/login" authentication-failure-url="/403"
                default-target-url="/admin"
                username-parameter="login" password-parameter="password" />
    <logout logout-url="/logout" logout-success-url="/logoutSuccessful" delete-cookies="JSESSIONID" invalidate-session="true" />
</http>

<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider>
        <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="myDataSource"
                           users-by-username-query= "select login, password, 'true' from employee where login=?"
                           authorities-by-username-query= "select login, role from employee where login =?  " />
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>

<beans:import resource="data-source-cfg.xml"/>
</beans:beans>
```

How to fix this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

take a look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33599878/spring-security-authorize-tag-http-status-500), the problem you are getting is about the spring version. You have two options:

1 - To keep using spring security 4.0.3 you must upgrade Spring version for 4.2.x.

2 - To keep using your current spring version you must downgrade to the Spring security 4.0.2

Best Regards

Comment: I've just tried and saw your post). Works with spring-security 4.0.1.release